Installing LyX 2.4.0 on Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS (Jammy)
The latest version of LyX, 2.4.0, was released on May 31, 2024. I attempted to install this version on my system running Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS (Jammy) by following the steps provided in the official LyX wiki at LyXOnUbuntu. However, despite my efforts, I could only install the older version, LyX 2.3.6.1-1, on Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS (Jammy).
I am unsure if there is a specific step or prerequisite that I might be missing which is preventing me from successfully installing the latest version of LyX. Could anyone provide guidance or clarify the correct procedure for installing LyX 2.4.0 on Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS (Jammy)?
Here’s what I did:

Followed the instructions from the LyX wiki page.
Added the appropriate repositories as mentioned.
Updated the package lists and attempted the installation.

Despite these steps, the installation defaults to the older version. I would appreciate any insights or additional steps needed to install LyX 2.4.0.

That is the latest stable version, if you want to install the trial version (not recommended) you must add the corresponding ppa: sudo add-apt-repository ppa:lyx-devel/daily --- You must remove the previous version: sudo apt remove lyx sudo apt autoremove and install trial version: sudo apt update sudo apt install lyx
